# Parse Rest API - Push Notification With Advanced Targeting Error

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I have asked this question on Parse's forum but received no replies in 14 hours, so I am falling back on what was my first choice anyway, good ol SO.

I am testing sending push notifications using a query. I am pretty sure that I am using the correct installation id in the query. But the push is not getting sent to my device. Maybe there is something wrong with the syntax?

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: yyy" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"where":{"id":{"in":["8e40a0b9-edef-442b-ad1a-3b5eb8c7fd8b"]}},"data":{"alert":"d"}}'\
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Which gives the response:

```
{"result":true}
```

But the notification is not sent. On Parse's dashboard I see following:
[image]

[image]

Anyone here with experience with Parse API, know what might be wrong with my query or request? Also, if anyone has an opinion on this let me know: Do you see any potential problem with using the in query as done above if there are say 100s of installation ids that need to be notified?

Comment: Just found that if I use `$in` instead of `in` in the query,Parse dashboard reports that the push was successful although it still says it was sent to 0 subscribers and I still dont get notification on my device.

Comment: are you sure you have registered subscribers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution. Two things were wrong with my query: First I was using `in` instead of `$in`. Second, my constraint was on `id`, it needed to be `installationId`. Following worked:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: yyy" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"where":{"installationId":{"$in":["8e40a0b9-edef-442b-ad1a-3b5eb8c7fd8b"]}},"data":{"alert":"d"}}'\
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Comment: Many thanx! Hard to find this solution.